# Hibernate mapping to same entity doesn't allow empty value

Tags: java, hibernate

I am doing a long overdue upgrade from Hibernate 3.6.5 to 5.1.

I have a mapping from a class Lead to itself as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lead", uniqueConstraints = { })
public class Lead implements Serializable {

    private int leadid;

    // More fields

    private Set<Lead> duplicateLeadChildren;
    private Lead duplicateLeadParent;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="leadid", unique=true, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=true)
    public int getLeadid() {
        return this.leadid;
    }
    public void setLeadid(int leadid) {
        this.leadid = leadid;
    }

    // More setters and getters

    /**
     * Returns a set of leads that has been marked as duplicates of this lead.
     * @return
     */
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="leadduplicate"
        , joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="parentleadid")}
        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="childleadid")})
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    public Set<Lead> getDuplicateLeadChildren(){
        return duplicateLeadChildren;
    }

    public void setDuplicateLeadChildren(Set<Lead> duplicateLeadChildren) {
        this.duplicateLeadChildren = duplicateLeadChildren;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a lead if this lead has been marked as a duplicate.
     *
     * The returned lead is the lead that should be used as the main lead in all future contact with the company.
     * @return
     */
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name="leadduplicate"
        , joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="childleadid")}
        , inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="parentleadid")})
    @NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    public Lead getDuplicateLeadParent(){
        return duplicateLeadParent;
    }

    public void setDuplicateLeadParent(Lead duplicateLeadParent) {
        this.duplicateLeadParent = duplicateLeadParent;
    }
}
```

This has worked for years. After upgrading to 5.1.14.Final or 5.2.17.Final, if I create a Lead and try to save it,

```
final Lead lead = new Lead();
// Removed setting some other fields removed from the class above
session.saveOrUpdate(lead);
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : ***.Lead.duplicateLeadParent
```

The mapping doesn't state that it has to be not-null. Explicitly setting `optional=true`, which is default, to the `@ManyToOne` annotation of the duplicateLeadParent doesn't help.

It sounds kind of similar to the issue here: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-11596 but using a version later than the fix version for that issue (5.2.10) doesn't help.

Comment: Are you sure that the duplicateLeadParent doesn't reference a transient instance at the point in time when you call saveOrUpdate?

Comment: Yes, it is null. My question is why hibernate states that it is a not-null property, it is supposed to allow null.

Comment: Yes, that's weird. It *could* mean that the property is "not-null and referencing a null value" *or* "just referencing a transient value (while not being a not-null property)".